# Problem with word "Nestlé" in an XML doc (UTF-8 encoding) using NXXMLParser. Any idea?

Tags: objective-c, xml, parsing, encoding, nsxmlparser

We are using NSXMLParser in Objective-C to parse our XML document, which are all UTF-8 encoded. One document has a string "Nestlé" in it (as in `...<title>Nestlé Novelties</title>...`). The parser just quit, reporting an error with error code=9, due to the French letter "e" at the end of the word "Nestle". Furthermore, we tried using IE, Chrome, Safari to show the same document directly. They reported a similar encoding error.

We are using UTF-8 for all incoming XML document, which means that all of them have "`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>`" as the top of the document.

Is this an encoding problem? If so, how do we solve this? What encoding should we use for all of our XML documents? Thanks in advance!

Barclay

Comment: really mysterious! Can you please whittle the doc down to the smallest that will give an issue, and edit your question to show it (with proper formatting -- highlight the XML code and click the icon that looks like zeros and ones).

Comment: It must be the name of an international industrial congolomerate causing  this disorder

Comment: Replace with "The maker of Nesquik."

Comment: Simply saying in the prolog that the document is UTF-8 doesn't make it true.  It sounds to me like it's really a single-byte encoding like ISO-8859-1.

Answer (score 6):

Have you checked the file with a hex editor to verify that the "é" is indeed UTF-8, `0xC3` `0xA9` ?

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, I would use `Nestl&eacute;` Does that work for your application?

Comment: Wouldn't work in XML -- only HTML (and XHTML) contain the '&eacute;' entity.

Answer (score -1):

Something I saw just now in an example XML file was that a string containing user-defined input (which happened to include é characters) wrapped the contents of the containing tag in CDATA declarations. This has the effect of making the parser completely ignore the characters contained therein.